# How to delete a key from a complex map?

Tags: go

I'm aware of the function `delete(...)`. But I have an array of maps:

```
[
  {key: "aa", value1: 1, value2: "33"},
  {key: "bb", value1: 23, value2: "333"},
  {key: "cc", value1: 33, value2: "3366"},
  {key: "yy", value1: 99, value2: "666"},
  // other items
]
```

How would I delete the items from this structure which have certain `key`-s ? Let's say, `key == "bb"` and `key == "yy"`

Note that the real size of this array is bigger - dozens or hundreds of items. As such, I'd prefer a performant solution.

Comment: This is not a complex map, this is a slice of documents (that may be maps). Iterate over the slice, and if the document (or map) contains the key, remove the slice element (as you would remove elements from any other slice).

Comment: @icza show how.

Comment: Please read this: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

Comment: @arumichi keep in mind this is not a code writing service - *you* write the code and *we* help you fix it.  You haven't written any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a standard trick of moving things down in the slice as you iterate, and then truncating at the end.

```
j := 0
for _, v := range mySlice {
    if v.key != "bb" && v.key != "yy" {
        mySlice[j] = v
        j++
    }
}
mySlice = mySlice[:j]
```

This uses O(1) extra memory, and is efficient.

In go1.18, you'll be able to write a generic function (which is typically called filter) to do the slicing. Here's a complete example, which you can also [run on the gotip playground.](https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/gKkyoJvjlTV)

```
package main

import "fmt"

// filter returns a slice (reusing the backing array of m), that
// contains all the elements of m for which f returns true.
func filter[T any](m []T, f func(*T) bool) []T {
    j := 0
    for i := range m {
        if f(&m[i]) {
            m[j] = m[i]
            j++
        }
    }
    return m[:j]
}

type data struct {
    key    string
    value1 int
    value2 string
}

func main() {
    xs := []data{
        {key: "aa", value1: 1, value2: "33"},
        {key: "bb", value1: 23, value2: "333"},
        {key: "cc", value1: 33, value2: "3366"},
        {key: "yy", value1: 99, value2: "666"},
    }
    xs = filter(xs, func(x *data) bool { return x.key != "bb" && x.key != "yy" })
    fmt.Println(xs)
}
```

Comment: What's `[T any]` ? Golang has introduced generics??

Comment: @arumichi no, not until go1.18 which is due to be released in February :)

Comment: @icza you're right. I naively assumed that if the backing array was not accessible, values in it would not be live. But I checked and I believe they are still live. I updated the answer to remove this part.

Comment: FYI your first code snippet does not delete keys `bb` & `yy` - instead it deletes all keys *except* those two.

Comment: @colm.anseo thankyou for your astute observation. I have negated the condition.

Comment: Why did you define the generic version to accept a slice of `T` and then require a `*T` as the argument of the filter function?